# Thread.exit() Line: not Available?? Edit Source Lookup Path?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, exit

Java Class:

```
package com.org.spring;
public class Restuarent {

public void greatingMessage() {
    System.out.println("Welcome..");
 }
}
```

Java Class For Test Spring:

```
public class TestSpringPro {

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springConfig.xml");
    Restuarent restObj = (Restuarent) context.getBean("restuarentBean");

    restObj.greatingMessage();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }

   }
 }
```

XML : bean Configuration

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="restuarentBean" class="com.org.spring.Restuarent">
   </bean>
   </beans>
```

I am new to java as i bit confused while debugging this simple spring program at the end i am going to the "Thread.exit() Line: not Available" but while simply running no error is coming why please let me know. i know this might be simple but thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window->Preferences, Java->Installed JRE's, clicked on my JRE and clicked
Edit.  Now click Add External Jar , go to your java path 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60" like this and find src.zip and add this 
 After this, I verified it worked.